# Android adb not allowing me to go into read-write mode

Tags: android, adb, hosts

I am trying to upload a hosts file to my android emulator, and I have followed and Google'd everywhere, but I cannot get my emulator to go into `rw` mode so I can upload my hosts file to it.

First I startup my Emulator so it shows up in the device list.

Next I log into the shell from the commandline:

```
$ adb.exe shell
```

Next I run the following command:

```
root@generic_x86:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
```

I then get the following message:

> mount: Read-only file system

Why can I not change the settings?

This is what I was following: https://end0tknr.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/edit-hosts-file-via-android-device-monitor-in-android-studio-and-adb-shell/

Comment: I think only root can do that. try out "su". Maybe your device must be rooted.

Comment: It should be running as root... as it says `root@...`

Comment: Hm, `mount -o rw,remount /system` works without problems in Genymotion emulator (Android 4.2.2). It's rooted, but as I can see your emulator is also rooted

Answer (score 0):

try changing the settings by opening the emulator from command prompt in writable system mode

*sdkpath/emulator -avd  -writable-system*

and then follow root, remount,shell....